# Why does trying to compute $\lim_{x\to-\infty} {2x-1\over \sqrt{3x^2+x+1}}$ result in the negative of the answer given?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

My textbook asks me to evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x\to-\infty} {2x-1\over \sqrt{3x^2+x+1}}$$ which evaluates to $-2\over\sqrt{3}$. The method in the book is to factor out $x^2$ from the root in the denominator:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to-\infty} {2x-1\over \sqrt{3x^2+x+1}} & = \lim_{x\to-\infty} {2x-1\over \sqrt{x^2\left(3+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}} \\
 & = \lim_{x\to-\infty} {2x-1\over -x\sqrt{3+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}} \\
 & = \lim_{x\to-\infty} {-2+\frac{1}{x}\over \sqrt{3+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}} \\
 & = {-2\over\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}$$

the second step is justified because $x\to-\infty$ implies $x\lt0$, so $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$.

For my attempt I ended up with the negative of the correct answer:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to-\infty} {2x-1\over \sqrt{3x^2+x+1}} & = \lim_{x\to-\infty} \left({2x-1\over \sqrt{3x^2+x+1}}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}}\right) \\
 & = \lim_{x\to-\infty} {2-\frac{1}{x}\over \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}\left(3x^2+x+1\right)}} \\
 & = \lim_{x\to-\infty} {2-\frac{1}{x}\over \sqrt{3+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}} \\
 & = {2\over\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}$$

Where have I gone wrong? I suspect the mistake lies in my second step, but I'm unable to identify what went wrong exactly.

Comment: Also, thank you *very much* for including a full explanation of your thoughts, enough context to know what you can use, and a clear identification of where you think your error is. This is a *well-written question*.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that we must always check the conditions before applying any 'rule'. Relevant to this question is the fact that for reals $a,b,c$ we have $(a^b)^c = a^{b·c}$ **if** $a$ is **positive**, and not necessarily so otherwise: $((-1)^6)^{1/2} \ne (-1)^{6·1/2}$.

Comment: In the future, it may help to substitute $x$ with $-x$ when dealing with limits on the negative axis.

Comment: Note that $\displaystyle\,\sqrt{\,{a^{2}}\,}\, = \left\vert\,{a}\,\right\vert$

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your mistake is in writing

$$\frac 1 x = \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}}.$$

Since $x < 0$, the correct version includes a negative sign.